# How can I trigger the beforeCreate hook when bulkCreating in Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a `beforeCreate` hook in a Sequelize model (runs bcrypt on the password in a `User` table), and would like to create a user in the seed file. Functions like bulkCreate simply insert into the database, and so don't call any hooks (including the `createdAt`/`updatedAt`). How do I create with the hooks called in a way that matches the format required by the seeder?

It seems like many are just using `sequelize-fixtures`? Is this the way to go? Or I could just ignore the seed format, and use the standard .create/.build and .save format?

Also, where is documentation related to seeding located? The Google searches were pretty light in terms of info.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the `individualHooks` option to true when bulkCreating, as below:

```
User.bulkCreate(users, {individualHooks: true}).then(function() {
  console.log("Done!");
});
```

There's some documentation about this option [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html).

Also, if you're allowing users to change passwords, you should add a `beforeUpdate` hook as well. You can prevent the password from being processed by bcrypt two times (when properties of the User other than the password are updated) in the following way:

```
function hashPassword(user, options, fn) {
  //Don't hash if password is already hashed
  if (user.dataValues.password.indexOf('$2a$') === 0) {
    fn(null, user);
    return;
  }

  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error while generating hash!');
      fn(err, null);
      return;
    }
    user.password = hash;
    fn(null, user);
  });
}
```